# WordPress - need to fix enqueue script in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

How can I enqueue this particular script in functions.php?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" integrity="sha384-mE6eXfrb8jxl0rzJDBRanYqgBxtJ6Unn4/1F7q4xRRyIw7Vdg9jP4ycT7x1iVsgb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: See here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js

Answer (score 0):

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.3', true); 

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');
```

Can you try this

Comment: And what about this line?
integrity="sha384-mE6eXfrb8jxl0rzJDBRanYqgBxtJ6Unn4/1F7q4xRRyIw7Vdg9jP4ycT7x1iVsgb" crossorigin="anonymous"